# Reloading modules in a mod_wsgi daemon mode application

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, daemon, python-module

Is there a way to ensure all modules are cleared and freshly reloaded in a mod_wsgi application running in daemon mode? Is an Apache restart enough? Or does the daemon persist across restarts?

I've looked at the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode) but it still isn't clear to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try modifying the wsgi file. For ex in unix, touch 'wsgi.script' should do.

On the other hand restarting apache should definitely be enough.